# Centos Apache multi virtual host sendmail header info

Tags: virtualhost, sendmail

For example, Centos 6.8, server ip 1.2.3.4, and some domain added inside `vhost.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerAdmin email@example_1.com
   ServerName example_1.com
   ServerAlias www.example_1.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/example_1.com/public_html/
   ErrorLog /srv/www/example_1.com/logs/error.log 
   CustomLog /srv/www/example_1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerAdmin email@example_2.com
   ServerName example_2.com
   ServerAlias www.example_2.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/example_2.com/public_html/
   ErrorLog /srv/www/example_2.com/logs/error.log 
   CustomLog /srv/www/example_2.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And `etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost 
1.2.3.4 example_1.example_1.com example_1
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

For example if i send email from `example_2.com` to `example@gmail.com`, email original show alot of info about `example_1.com`.

```
Return-Path: <no-reply@example_2.com>
Received: from example_1.example_1.com (example_1.com. [...])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ...
        for <example@gmail.com>
        ...
        ...
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of no-reply@example_2.com designates ... as permitted sender) client-ip=...;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of no-reply@example_2.com designates ... as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=no-reply@example_2.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: by example_1.example_1.com (...) with ESMTP id ...;
Received: (from apache@localhost) by example_1.example_1.com ...
X-Authentication-Warning: example_1.example_1.com: apache set sender to no-reply@example_2.com using -f
```

How can i change the header info from all about `example_1.com` to `example_2.com` when i send email from `example_2.com`?

I have tried change the `vhost.conf` like below but still not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerAdmin email@example_2.com
  ServerName example_2.com
  ServerAlias www.example_2.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/example_2.com/public_html/
  ErrorLog /srv/www/example_2.com/logs/error.log 
  CustomLog /srv/www/example_2.com/logs/access.log combined

  <Directory /srv/www/example_2.com/public_html/>
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fno-reply@example_2.com"
  </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The actual `sendmail` that routes the messages works in the background. The `sendmail_path` only says how apache/php submits the messages to the actual background `sendmail`

The problem is that `sendmail` cannot dynamically use multiple hostnames. If you want to eradicate example_1 from the `Received` headers and similar, you have these alternative paths:

1. Set up another `sendmail` process on the same host, with a different configuration of a  `confDOMAIN_NAME` (gory details to be google'd).
2. Alternatively, change hostname of the server to some third neutral-sounding domain. Change `/etc/hosts` file so that first entry on `1.2.3.4` is `host.neutral-domain-3.com`. (The fact that currently the first entry is `example_1.example_1.com` is very probably the reason why you have this in the mail headers). If the `example_1.example_1.com` keeps showing in the headers, check if this is explicitly fixed somewhere in the sendmail configuration and change it too.
3. Alternatively, accept the headers as they are now. It's not very visible to users.

Please also make sure *not* to use domain names with an underscore `_` character.